# javascript Date().valueOf() is working on development PC but not on page served by server

Tags: javascript, date, value-of

The IE9 debugger (F12 developer tools -> script debugger) shows the following in the Locals window when I step through the code when the page is launched from the server:

```
 midnight  Fri Mar 15 00:00:00 EDT 2013      Object, (Date) 
 myDate    Fri Mar 15 00:00:00 EDT 2013      Object, (Date)
```

and yet the following conditional test for equality of value resolves to `false`:

```
 if (midnight.valueOf() === myDate.valueOf() ) {
    // these lines of code are never reached
     .
     .
     .
 }
```

The odd thing, the === test resolves to `true` on my development PC. I cannot figure out why it resolves to `false` on the page served up by the server. The debugger clearly indicates it should resolve to true.

The document is in "IE9 Standards" mode.

Comment: locale? still weird, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The valueOf method returns the primitive value of a Date object as a number data type, the number of milliseconds since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC.

The debugger only shows you the seconds so the variables may actually be different.

Comment: Should probably be a comment (the question/issue is currently vague), although it contains a clue: what *are* the actual epoch offsets?

Comment: @pst: chris pointed me in correct direction. When the dates were instantiated, they were instantiated: `var d = new Date(); d.setHours(0); d.setMinutes(0); d.setSeconds(0)`.   Now I've added `d.setMillseconds(0)`.